# Android Studio with gradle and Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, android-studio

I'm really stuck here. So, I follow this [tutorial](http://android.rzeszow.net/?p=79) step by step: but it still doesn't work.

I've done all steps from tutorial and find out what new module(GooglePlayServices) not in modules, if open `run->edit` configurations in `general->module` i don't see `GooglePlayServices`, I suppose this is the problem, but I can't find what I have to do to fix it.

Day early I tried same, but in this case (I actually don't remember what I did) `GooglePlayServices` in modules and I don't have anymore problem with `cannot resolve symbol 'maps'`, but it still doesn't work, fires error `Error inflating class fragment`

my activity extends `FragmentActivity`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

in both case `build.gradle` just like in tutorial:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(':GooglePlayServices')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

and `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':Roadatus', ':GooglePlayServices'
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: What's your main.xml?

Comment: In main.xml I have fragment from google documentation, but SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment. Add code to post.

Answer (score 28):

try to avoid including entire google play services,
it will force you to enable multidex due to the package size.
instead, include them individually,
eg:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

if you wish to include other services, please refer here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup (scroll down)

Comment: if you were forced to use multidex, here is an article on how to speed up multidex development http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177495/gradle-android-studio-build-too-slow-multidex-application

Comment: This answer helped me lot understanding the issue, but the actual `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'` causing a crash that `Error inflating class fragment crash`. While i update the play service version to latest one like `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'` the crash was resolved and finally i see my map <3

Comment: @RatulSharker there has been update, your version should be the right one

Answer (score 16):

I have tried and failed many a tutorial on this, but finally find a simple solution that seem to work.

I just installed Android Studio 0.2.3 on my mac, and these are the steps that made me view a maps fragment on a fresh hello world project template:

1) Click the SDK manager button in the toolbar in Android Studio.

2) Under 'Extras' locate 'Google play services' and download it.

3) in your build.gradle file in your src directory, add this line to dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
```

4) order and install your API-key following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

5) add the fragment to your layout xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

6) you should now be able to run your project on your device.

Comment: Please mind that the fragment must be `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` if you support older versions.

Answer (score 1):

In SDK manager install these from Extras:

- Android Support Repository
- Google Repository
- Google Play services

Then build.gradle should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    //compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }
}
```

I also had to comment this line in build.gradle:

```
//compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

More on this: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf