# Android Google Maps: XML layout errors

Tags: android, xml, android-mapview, android-studio, android-maps-v2

I am trying to get google maps v2 to work in android using android studio. I got all my keys and manifest setup. When I try and create xml for the actual activity that the map will show up on I get errors. My xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My error in android studio looks like this:

[image]

Comment: you need to include the google play services library.

Comment: see my answer maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me as well. Simply clean the project.

Comment: I am not familiar with Android Studio but for eclipse its Project-> clean. You may want to follow these instructions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135099/android-studio-with-gradle-and-google-maps-v2

Comment: a tutorial i found said rebuuild is the same as clean in android studio but it did not fix my problem

Answer (score -1):

hi you must use this code in xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: This looks pretty much identical to the `fragment` in the question.