# Failed to resolve: com.github.mopa11:MainDemo1:1.0.0

Tags: android, github, gradle

I am new for Github. 
Just now i have created a sample library project and uploaded on github. Now i want to use this library in my project but i am not able to import it.As it is throwing error

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.mopa11:MainDemo1:1.0.0.
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718820/failed-to-resolve-com-github-philjaympandroidchartv2-1-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244697/gradle-failed-to-resolve), but still am not able to import.

Answer (score 0):

Having your library hosted on Github does NOT make it available automatically. You need to either release it first, or try to use tools like http://jitpack.io/

Comment: https://jitpack.io/com/github/mopa11/MainDemo1/1.0.0/build.log maybe error while building can u help e out with it