# MultiDex error after updating GCM gradle

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-multidex

I was using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0'
```

in my application build.gradle and this in my project build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta2'
```

From last 10 days i was getting crash because of GCM at the time of InstanceId.
So i found that we need to update GCM to latest gradle so i did the same

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.0.2'
```

but now am getting Multidex error due to this. So i tried to resolve that too by following few steps like extending Application class with MultiDexApplication and all. Still getting the same issue.

My gradle dependencies

```
 compile project(':aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.9')
compile project(':aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.9')
compile project(':universal-image-loader-1.9.5')
compile project(':FlurryAnalytics-6.2.0')
compile project(':circularImageView')
compile project(':swipeMenuListView')
compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.2.0'
compile 'com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:1.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Tried cleaning and re building the project?

Comment: post your gradle code

Comment: please check my update

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle you may use this

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

So, remove it and use the needed API only,

Check the VicVu Answer in this link,
[gradle - Android Studio build too slow multidex application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177495/gradle-android-studio-build-too-slow-multidex-application)

Comment: Try to use single Image Loader API to reduce the size.
Here you are using squareup and Universal image loaders

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the heap size adjustment to your build.gradle file? For example this will set the max heap size for dexing to 4GB, and it will also enable
multiDexEnabled option.

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
     }
}
```